# LESS.css Nested Rules - is this valid LESS?

Tags: css, less

I wanted to make it easier to manage my font rules in LESS, so i created the following rule based on the Nested Rules section in the official LESS guide.

However, they only provide example for nested rules that contain additional classes, so i wanted to know if writing it this way is valid or not, and if not, is there a way i can make my code succinct and take advantage of nested rules?

I'd like to be able to use the nested rule feature to specify parameters for h1 and h3 for the .logo class.

```
//Fonts
.font-setup (@fontfamily, @fontsize, @fontweight, @fontcolor){
    font-family: @fontfamily;
    font-size: @fontsize;
    font-weight: @fontweight;
    color: @fontcolor;
}
```

```css
.logo {
    h1 {.font-setup ("Euphemia UCAS", 200px, normal, #222);}
    h3 {.font-setup ("Euphemia UCAS", 40px, normal, #222);}

    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
}
```

**Note:** I should point out that i'm building ontop of Bootstrap.less, so my classes are overriding their css. As i say, when i outputted this in less without using nested rules i had no problems

Comment: What does `.font-setup()` expand to?

Comment: I've had to remove the "@" symbol on StackOverflow as it wont let me paste that, but they're in my original code

//Fonts
 .font-setup (fontfamily, fontsize, fontweight, fontcolor){
            font-family: fontfamily;
      font-size: fontsize;
   font-weight: fontweight;
   color: fontcolor;
            }

Comment: Please place that into your question as an edit, not as a comment, including the `@`.

Comment: OK, i've done that. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it and see?

But yes, this is valid.

To clarify I have tested by putting the following at the end of one of my less files:

```
        .font-setup (@fontfamily, @fontsize, @fontweight, @fontcolor){
        font-family: @fontfamily;
        font-size: @fontsize;
        font-weight: @fontweight;
        color: @fontcolor;
        }

.logo {
    h1 {.font-setup ("Euphemia UCAS", 200px, normal, #222);}
    h3 {.font-setup ("Euphemia UCAS", 40px, normal, #222);}

    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
}
```

This has rendered out the following at the end of my CSS:

```
.logo {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
}
.logo h1 {
  font-family: "Euphemia UCAS";
  font-size: 200px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #222222;
}
.logo h3 {
  font-family: "Euphemia UCAS";
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #222222;
}
```

This is using DotLess but I would imagine it shoudl be the saem for everything.

I think you need to verify other parts of your file...

Comment: I posted the question after trying it, and it isnt working, even though previously i outputted the same css without nested rules. I have also checked it in tinkerbin and it *does* seem valid, but my page is now broken and the font size isnt being applied.

Any advice?

Comment: Is your `.font-setup` correctly defined and receiving the correct parameters? Does it work if you replace those elements with more "normal" things (eg just stick `display: block;` in them to check the general syntax).

Comment: Yes, it seems to be. I should point out that i'm building ontop of Bootstrap.less, so my classes are overriding their css. As i say, when i outputted this in less without using nested rules i had no problems. Should i post a link to where my code is hosted?

Comment: Just edited my post with clarification on why I say it should work. Does it work correctly if you take out these lines entirely? did you definitely change nothing apart from the nesting of this one ruleset?

Comment: I do indeed get the same output. I've realised that previously i was using just the logo class on it's own to apply to all tags. and had a generic class to override the bootstrap.less. To be fair, i'm now using the class and then the tag type, eg .logo h1, and it seem it is inheriting css for h1 from the original bootstrap. Is there a way to override the h1 for the original bootstrap? I know that i can modify the original bootstrap.less code, but if it doesnt affect performance i would prefer to add my own classes so that when bootstrap ever gets updated i dnt have to rewrite my code

Comment: Wait, when you say it isn't working do you mean the CSS isn't compiling or just the the styles aren't doing what you want? If its the latter that is a totally different question on CSS and nothing to do with your less and nesting...

Comment: The styles aren't working. I do apologise, but originally i thought this was because my nested rules syntax was incorrect, but now i realise it's due to the css styling.

Comment: I marked this as answered since you helped me to diagnose the LESS correctly and helped me to realise that the issue is not related to LESS but a css styling issue. I have posted a new question instead. Thank you for your help and my apologies once again for any inconvenience i caused you.

Comment: @KhuramMalik: That's cool. I've had problems myself with LESS so happy to help. I'll go take a look at your new question when I get a chance and see if I can help (if nobody else has yet).